# DrawingBrush.GeometryDrawing with dynamic Brush property

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, dynamicresource

I'm trying to dynamically change the `Brush` of a `GeometryDrawing` inside a `DrawingBrush` by setting a `DynamicResource`.

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="Vector.Close" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Element.Glyph.Strong}" Geometry="F1 M 38.199,40 L 0,1.801 L 1.801,0 L 40,38.199 L 38.199,40 Z"/>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Element.Glyph.Strong}" Geometry="F1 M 1.801,40 L 0,38.199 L 38.199,0 L 40,1.801 L 1.801,40 Z"/>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

When I change the color scheme of my app, I shift the ordering of my `ResourceDictionary` by `Remove()` and `Insert()` in the `MergedDictionary`:

```
public static void SelectTheme(string id = "Light")
{
    var theme = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Source != null && f.Source.ToString().EndsWith($"Colors/{id}.xaml"));

    if (theme == null)
    {
        theme = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Source != null && f.Source.ToString().EndsWith("Colors/Light.xaml"));
        UserSettings.All.MainTheme = AppTheme.Light;
    }

    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(theme);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);
}
```

For example, inside the `Light.xaml`, I have a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Element.Glyph.Strong" Color="#FF231F20"/>
```

Inside the `App.xaml`, I import both my resource dictionaries (the order does not matter, since the resources will be shifted to the last position):

```
<!--Themes-->
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Colors/Dark.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Colors/Light.xaml"/>

<ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Vectors.xaml"/>

<ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Button.xaml"/>
```

---

The vector is used as an icon on a custom `Button`. Inside the button there's a Border with a sizing and alignment, and the vector is used as the `Background`.

`Button` definition and usage (`Icon` is a `Brush` `DependencyProperty`):

```
public class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Icon), typeof(Brush), typeof(ExtendedButton));

    public Brush Icon
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(IconProperty);
        set => SetCurrentValue(IconProperty, value);
    }

    //Ctor and other stuff.
}

<n:ExtendedButton Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.NoText}" 
                  Icon="{DynamicResource Vector.Close}" Width="30" Padding="6"/>
```

I was setting the `Icon` as a `StaticResource`, but I changed to `DynamicResource` before asking in here, as a test. But it still didn't work.

Here's the simplified `Style` for the button:

```
<!--Button • No Border • No Text-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type n:ExtendedButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" x:Key="Style.Button.NoText">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type n:ExtendedButton}">
                <Border x:Name="MainBorder" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{DynamicResource Element.Opacity}"
                                Height="14" Width="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush.Button.Background.Hover}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush.Button.Background.Pressed}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

The rest of the app works, when changing the theme, everything else changes. The `Element.Glyph.Strong` inside the `GeometryDrawing` does not update.

Only when closing the app and opening again will display the vector with the correct color, since it loads with the new theme.

I guessed that the `Brush` property, as a `DependencyProperty` would update when the resource updated too.

I wonder how could I set the `Brush` with a dynamic color, without having to work with code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you are changing themes, but if other components are changing then I am assuming you are doing that correctly.

I think the key is to make sure you are using `Background="{DynamicResource Vector.Close}"` instead of `Background="{StaticResource Vector.Close}"`.

`Dictionary1.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Element.Glyph.Strong" Color="Black" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Dictionary2.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Element.Glyph.Strong" Color="Yellow" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Dictionary3.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="Vector.Close" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Element.Glyph.Strong}" Geometry="F1 M 38.199,40 L 0,1.801 L 1.801,0 L 40,38.199 L 38.199,40 Z"/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Element.Glyph.Strong}" Geometry="F1 M 1.801,40 L 0,38.199 L 38.199,0 L 40,1.801 L 1.801,40 Z"/>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Button Background="{DynamicResource Vector.Close}" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ChangeTheme_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
// stuff up here...

public string currentDict = "Dictionary1.xaml";

private void ChangeTheme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentDict == "Dictionary1.xaml")
    {
        currentDict = "Dictionary2.xaml";
    } else
    {
        currentDict = "Dictionary1.xaml";
    }
    var app = (App)Application.Current;
    app.ChangeTheme(new Uri(currentDict, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

`App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary3.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`App.xaml.cs`

```
public void ChangeTheme(Uri uri)
{
    var dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = uri };
    var dict2 = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Dictionary3.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict2);
}
```

Obviously this is a little messy and hacky, but it works:

[image: Button with black x]

[image: Button with yellow x]

---

Edit:

I am not able to reproduce even when using the custom styling. Here it is after switching:

[image: two buttons, both yellow]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of details. I updated the question. I'm using a custom button with a `Style`.  Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I tried to simply use your `Button`, as written above instead of mine. The color still does not change.

Comment: As an aside: I like using `ContentControls` for my icons. I put a canvas and a path (from an svg) inside of it. Then set that as the Content of the button. I use `TemplateBinding` to the `Foreground` of the button for the path color.

Comment: I see what's happening now. You remove the dictionary with the vector and add it again. That refreshes all dynamic resources inside. In my case I'm just switching the position of the color dictionaries.