# DrawingImage with DynamicResource in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, drawing, dynamicresource

I have multiple DrawingImages in a dictionary. I also have a IconAccentBrush for those Images.
I want to change dynamically the color in my drawing images. I have a slider that changes the IconAccentBrush.

I want to reference my DrawingImage with a key.

If I don't reference the DrawingGroup, it colour will change, but if I reference it **from another project**, it won't.

Can you help ?

Thank you,
Olivier

Example that the icon will appear, but the colours won't change:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
....
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourcesWpf;component/Dictionaries/ImageDictionary.xaml" />
....
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

----------------------------------------------------------
//this is ImageDictionary.xaml

<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DrawingGroup x:Key="PushPinActiveDrawingGroup"  ClipGeometry="M-19,1 V512.9995 H492 V-19 H1 Z">
            <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                <TranslateTransform X="19" Y="-0.00097703933715820313" />
            </DrawingGroup.Transform>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry1}" />
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry2}" />
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry3}" />
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry4}" />
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry5}" />
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry6}" />
</DrawingGroup>
</ResourceDictionary>

----------------------------------------------------------

<ToggleButton  Margin="{StaticResource MainThickness}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPinned}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage Drawing="{DynamicResource PushPinActiveDrawingGroup}"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</ToggleButton>
```

Example that the icon will appear, but the colours will change:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="{StaticResource MainThickness}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPinned}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M-19,1 V512.9995 H492 V-19 H1 Z">
                        <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="19" Y="-0.00097703933715820313" />
                        </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry1}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry2}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry3}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry4}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry5}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource IconAccentBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource ApplyColorGeometry6}" />
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: I guess you failed to wire up that Drawing with ToggleButton or resouces used in that Drawing. Where is PushPinActiveDrawingGroup and it can be referenced by ToggleButton?

Comment: Hi, the icon is showing but the colours don't change if it's referenced in the Drawing. I would like to have the colours changed while it's referenced.

Comment: Can not reproduce the issue. For me, changing a Brush resource that is used by a GeometryDrawing child of a DrawingGroup resource just works. Both resources are elements of the same ResourceDictionary. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited my example that did not work. I think It wasn't clear that the resource wasn't in the same ResourceDictionary as you say but in an other project. 

It works if it's in the same ResourceDictionary or the same project.

Comment: It seems that I found someone with the same problem, it may help you understand : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852845/drawingbrush-geometrydrawing-with-dynamic-brush-property

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the color of the icon by changing the source in the image style.

Here is the solution:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="{StaticResource MainThickness}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPinned}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PushPinActiveDrawingImage}" />
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</ToggleButton>
```